# Android app crashes when connecting to mongodb

Tags: android, mongodb, nullpointerexception

I'm new to Android development and in my first application I'm trying to connect to mongodb. What have been done:

1. Installed latest Android Studio (2.2.3) on Windows 10.
2. Added dependency to application build.gradle:

`compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.2'`

3. Code to connect to mongodb:

   ```
       MongoClientURI mongoUri  = new MongoClientURI("..."); // here specified the connection string that worked fine for desktop mongodb client
       MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri);
   ```

Everything compiled and deployed to a virtual device successfully. But when I try to execute this line:
 `new MongoClient(mongoUri);`

an exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.security.CodeSource java.security.ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource()' on a null object reference.
```

In debug I can see that ProtectionDomain implementation just returns null. However mongodb expects some reasonable value from that method.

According to other questions on StackOverflow it seems that people are able to connect to mongodb using such an approach. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Like most remote databases, you ideally should not do this and instead setup a REST API between your app and the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mongo Java Driver **should not be used on Android** because it's not designed for Android JRE (which is not *exactly* Java JRE). Android JRE has some limitations, especially on cryptography and security classes, and that's why the Mongo Driver does not run on Android.

As suggested by cricket_007, to support Android apps, you should write a REST or SOAP API in Java that uses Mongo driver to get and manipulate your data, and then serve them with an HTTP Server.

From the Android app, you will call your REST API instead of Mongo driver directly.